# Rails error use rails s or other command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby version = 2.4.0
rails version = 5

I use command rails s output is

> /Users/andrewkusuma/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::VERSION

how to fix this?
all rails command have similar output problem

thank you, I dont know what called this error

Comment: That is a warning, not an error... does your rails command still run? if so - you can probably ignore the warning. What happened when you googled for this phrase? why were the results not satisfactory?

Comment: Following [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41994190/2753913), try reinstall openssl gem with version 2.0.2