# Fresh install of Rails and getting OpenSSL errors: "already initialized constant OpenSSL"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am stuck trying to get going with RoR. I did the Ruby Installfest, but am running into an issue with what I think is openssl.bundle.

I am using RVM, and am running Rails 5.0.1 and Ruby 2.4.0

I tried a full removal/fresh start by using `rvm implode` and went through and reinstalled everything following [RailsApps Guide](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html) but am still seeing the identical error. I am running the latest version of macOS Sierra.

This is the output I get when running $Rake -T in my_app.

```
richsmith@Richs-MacBook-Pro:~/workspace/myapp$ rake -T
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::VERSION
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_FIPS
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Config::DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::Signer
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::TEXT
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOCERTS
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOSIGS
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOCHAIN
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOINTERN
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOVERIFY
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::DETACHED
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOATTR
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOSMIMECAP
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::UNIVERSALSTRING
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::CHARACTER_STRING
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::BMPSTRING
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/pkey.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::DH::DEFAULT_1024
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/pkey.rb:8: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_1024 was here
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/pkey.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::DH::DEFAULT_2048
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/pkey.rb:17: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_2048 was here
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/pkey.rb:30: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::DEFAULT_TMP_DH_CALLBACK
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/pkey.rb:30: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_TMP_DH_CALLBACK was here
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of AES was here
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::CAST5
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of CAST5 was here
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::BF
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of BF was here
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::DES
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of DES was here
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::IDEA
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of IDEA was here
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC2
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC2 was here
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC4
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC4 was here
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC5
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC5 was here
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES128 was here
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES192
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES192 was here
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES256 was here
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
rake aborted!
TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Cipher
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `require'
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails.rb:11:in `require'
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/richsmith/workspace/myapp/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
/Users/richsmith/workspace/myapp/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/richsmith/workspace/myapp/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/Users/richsmith/workspace/myapp/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/richsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

gem uninstall openssl -v 2.0.3

gem install openssl -v 2.0.2

That should fix it.

Comment: You were absolutely right. The issue seems to be stemming from v. 2.0.3 but when I went back a version, it works fine. Any ideas why?

Comment: actually, you don't need to reinstall openssl again. openssl is one of default built-in gems.

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks!

Comment: You're a genius! StackOverflow to the rescue :)

Answer (score 10):

I solved this by adding the line:

gem 'openssl', '>=2.0.3'

to my gemfile. Apparently bundler is loading both the default 2.0.2 version as well as the new 2.0.3 version. The line above prevents this.

Comment: I prefer your solution. Downgrading openSSL seems more dangerous than anything else.

Answer (score 5):

Solved this 3 hours later. The issue was as apparent in the log files, something goofy happened to openSSL.

The solution was to:

1. Remove all traces of the issue `rvm implode`
2. From there I did a fresh install of rvm using `$ \curl -L
   https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`
3. Closed and reopened the terminal.
4. Installed Ruby `$ rvm install ruby-2.4.0`
5. Updated the gem manager `$ gem update --system`
6. Changed to the global gemset using `$ rvm gemset use global`
7. Then updated all gems using `$ gem update`
8. From here I installed bundler and Nokogiri (not sure if it is a dependent for openSSL but wasn't taking chances) using `$ gem install bundler` and `gem install nokogiri`
9. From here I made a new gemset to install rails in using `$ rvm use ruby-2.4.0@rails5.0 --create`
10. Then I installed the latest version of rails using `$ gem install rails`
11. Not wanting to take chances at this point, I removed openSSL using `gem uninstall openssl`
12. Then reinstalled it with `gem install openssl`
13. Lastly, I closed my terminal, reopened it and voila, it worked!

I am very new to this so there may be redundancies here for sure, but I know this solution cleaned everything up and worked.

Comment: You upgraded openssl to latest version, it is not a reinstall of the same version.