# ruby on rails setup problems: already initialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to launch a rail project using rails server. But I received following error message:

```
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::VERSION
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_FIPS
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Config::DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::Signer
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::TEXT
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOCERTS
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOSIGS
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOCHAIN
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOINTERN
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_TLS_D5_BUG
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_TLS_BLOCK_PADDING_BUG
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_ALL
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SESSION_RESUMPTION_ON_RENEGOTIATION
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_SINGLE_DH_USE
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_EPHEMERAL_RSA
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_TLS_ROLLBACK_BUG
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv2
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv3
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_TLSv1
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_TLSv1_1
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_TLSv1_2
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_TICKET
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_IGNORE_CRITICAL
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_X509_STRICT
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_ALLOW_PROXY_CERTS
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_POLICY_CHECK
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_EXPLICIT_POLICY
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_INHIBIT_ANY
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_INHIBIT_MAP
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_NOTIFY_POLICY
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_EXTENDED_CRL_SUPPORT
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_USE_DELTAS
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_CHECK_SS_SIGNATURE
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_NO_ALT_CHAINS
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SSL_CLIENT
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SSL_SERVER
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_NS_SSL_SERVER
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SMIME_SIGN
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SMIME_ENCRYPT
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_CRL_SIGN
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_ANY
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_OCSP_HELPER
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_TIMESTAMP_SIGN
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_COMPAT
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_SSL_CLIENT
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_SSL_SERVER
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_EMAIL
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_OBJECT_SIGN
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_OCSP_SIGN
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_OCSP_REQUEST
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_TSA
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_AREA
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_DIR
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_DIR_ENV
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE_ENV
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_PRIVATE_DIR
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_INTERNALERROR
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_MALFORMEDREQUEST
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_NOSTATUS
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_SIGREQUIRED
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_SUCCESSFUL
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_TRYLATER
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_AFFILIATIONCHANGED
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_CACOMPROMISE
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC2
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC2 was here
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC4
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC4 was here
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC5
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC5 was here
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES128 was here
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES192
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES192 was here
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES256 was here
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64:in `<class:Cipher>': superclass mismatch for class Cipher (TypeError)
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:16:in `<module:OpenSSL>'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.rb:17:in `require'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails.rb:11:in `require'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in `require'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in `require_command!'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:83:in `server'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dingqituo/summer_school/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/dingqituo/summer_school/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /Users/dingqituo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dingqituo/summer_school/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    from /Users/dingqituo/summer_school/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993527/fresh-install-of-rails-and-getting-openssl-errors-already-initialized-constant

Answer (score 1):

There's currently an [issue open in OpenSSL](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/issues/103) on this. Try specifying `gem 'openssl', '2.0.2'` in your Gemfile and see how it goes.

Note: I'd recommend watching the issue and upgrading to the latest openssl once it's resolved, as it's certainly best to keep openssl up-to-date where possible!